# Type error primeFactors.for is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I've got a 'TypeError: primeFactors.for is not a function' error from Jasmine when I try to run this code, I've run into this type of error so many times. What's the best way to resolve it? I know that clearly .for is not a function but I'm not sure why?

```
var primeFactors = function(){};

primeFactors.prototype.for = function(num){
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 2; i < Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(num)); i++){
        if(num % i === 0){
            array.push(i);
            num = num/i;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return array;
};


module.exports = primeFactors;
```

Comment: There's no line os Jasmine test code, why the tag [tag:jasmine]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to call `.for`, you must create an object instance for that prototype, for instance with the `new` keyword:

This is not OK:

```
 primeFactors.for(3);
```

But this is OK:

```
 var obj = new primeFactors;
 obj.for(3);
```

For your Jasmine test, it would work like this:

```
 it('returns an empty array for 1', function() {
     expect((new primeFactors).for(1)).toEqual([]);
 });
```

Comment: it('returns an empty array for 1', function() {
    expect(primeFactors.for(1)).toEqual([]);
  }); if wanted it to pass this test how would I reformulate it

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case the tests are correctly written you can use static functions (inside classes) to pass them.
Take a look at: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes/static

```
"use strict";

class primeFactors {
    static for(num) {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 2; i < Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(num)); i++){
        if(num % i === 0){
            array.push(i);
            num = num/i;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return array;
    }
};

module.exports = primeFactors;
```